# Ansible regexp for Apache VirtualHost line

Tags: ansible

I want to replace `<VirtualHost *:80>` to `<VirtualHost *:443>` in my apache configuration file using ansible. How should I do that? I tried below but that did not help:

```
- name: Enable SSL port
  replace: dest="/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf"
           regexp='^<VirtualHost *:80>'
           replace='<VirtualHost *:443>'
  become: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work, because of the `*` (a regular expression repetition marker) in the `regexp`. You should escape it with `\` to match the `*` character in the target file:

```
regexp='^<VirtualHost \*:80>'
```

---

However:

- it is rather cumbersome to use Ansible's `replace` module to edit Apache configuration files. Apache already makes it easy for you to put the configuration in separate files, reads and combines them automatically. Use `copy` or `template` instead;
- don't save the configuration files directly to `sites-enabled`, they should be stored in `sites-available` and symlinked from `sites-enabled` (it might not matter to you, but this is for Apache's `a2ensite` and `a2dissite` commands).

Comment: Thanks @techraf. it did help me!